# Kubernetes CGE logging to kibana logging

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm looking for a way to change the logging for my Kubernetes cluster which is running on Google' Container Engine. I don't really like the GCE logging and want to replace it with Kibana.

Is there a way to replace the logging service to Kibana without having to create a new cluster?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own Kibana. Its rc and svc yamls can be found here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch

I don't know if you have elasticsearch running already?